# UIPageViewController with three UIViewControllers without UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

Can anyone tell me how UIPageViewController with three ViewControllers without UIScrollView will work. I searched so many tutorials I didn't find the correct one. I am new to Xcode.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to understand how internally it works, it seams, that it use UIPanGestureRecognizer to detect swipes and just move Views of geted View Controllers. And closed PageCurl api, if user select PageCurl Effect.

If You want just use it - this solution are useful:

[for storyboad](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)
[for just code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21025367/DoubleSidedPageViewController-master.zip)